# Does Oracle's GuardedString protect sensitive data against heap or memory dumps?

Tags: encryption, java, memory

Oracle's `org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString` states this in its documentation:

> The GuardedString class alleviates [the problem that string data is kept in memory as clear text] by storing the characters in memory in an encrypted form. The encryption key will be a randomly-generated key.

Does this protect against a heap or memory dump? At first glance, it seems trivial to locate the randomly-generated key in memory, and to use it to decrypt the sensitive data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some deeper look into the actual implementation will help an attacker understand the data structure of a memory dump, and from what I found in [EncryptorImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.connid/connid-framework-internal/1.3.3/org/identityconnectors/common/security/impl/EncryptorImpl.java#EncryptorImpl) there has been put no effort into obfuscating the key storage mechanism to prolong the time needed for reverse-engineering the secret. So no, this is not an effective measure against exposure of memory.

Let me provide a better usage scenario for this class:
As the key variable is private, at least it's very unlikely a developer would find his way around responding with the key by accident to an attacker (e.g. due to a bug in the control flow of a web service request handler), so there is some use for this class in ensuring the code can only help decrypting by actually decrypting in the background instead of handing out a key. After the program is stopped / taken offline, an attacker won't be able to decrypt secrets anymore, and all decryption that happened until then (when the attacker was using the program as a kind of oracle) had a chance to be logged, which can be relevant in a post-mortem analysis to figure out what data has been compromised.

Comment: Worth adding: This is Java's equivalent of .Net's SecureString.  The .Net team now acknowledges that SecureString is [not as good as advertised](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28xZ7Xb5MhE) ("really should be called LessInsecureString"), and it is not supported in .Net core.

Comment: Yeah, I've been saying for years the dotnet(fw) SecureString should have been called "KindaSecureString" :)    To alleviate that false sense of security (pun intended).

Comment: @Anton.  The provided link appears to be dead. Consider updating it if you get a chance.